# How do I fix UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `docker.for.mac.localhost' issue and connect to LocalStack from an Express server?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, localstack

I am using LocalStack in a Docker Container to mock/host some AWS services locally e.g. SSM and DynamoDB. Using AWS CLI, these services are accessible on:-

```
docker.for.mac.localhost
```

I am using Express to debug a Lambda handler which fails to access these same services and gets the following types of error:-

```
ERROR: SSMError: Config could not be read from AWS Parameter Store{"data":{"name":"/ps/LOCAL/nationalGrid/metering/bmuAssetAttributeMap"}} --- UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `docker.for.mac.localhost'. This service may not be available in the `eu-west-1' region.
```

In the SSM and DynamoDB wrapper code the endpoint value is getting passed into the AWS SDK as:-

```
http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4566
```

However, it seems like, from a networking or DNS perspective, the Lambda that uses these services and is being triggered by Express does not have access to the mock LocalStack service running on this address in Docker.

Please can anyone advise on what might be the issue and how to resolve?

FYI We can trigger the Lambda using SAM Local correctly BUT we want the Webstorm IDE debugging capability which is why we are using Express.

Thanks!

Sam

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

In case it helps anyone else with this issue. For SAM Local the address for LocalStack endpoints in our setup needs to be:-

```
http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4566
```

But for Express it needs to be:-

```
http://localhost:4566
```